# Spring batch using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I hava a spring batch application using spring boot and I run this job using the maven command : `mvn spring-boot:run`.

When I kill the process using `CTRL+C`, the application exit but if I look at spring-batch-admin UI the "Last JobExecution Duration" value continue to increase and I can't start the application because of "A job execution for this job is already running".

How should I properly kill the job when using batch with spring-boot?

Comment: you need to show code so we know as what `JobParameters` you use when you launch your jobs and also you should try to close context.

Comment: It seems you are launching same job instance again and again. Job instances need to distinguish themselves. Also, you need to check if `pid` disappears or not.

Comment: Here's how I launch the job `mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="--timestamp=123456"`.

Comment: And also, every time I start the job, the job appends all the previous parameters even if I put zero of them ... `Job: [FlowJob: [name=Open]] completed with the following parameters: [{-param=value5, -timestamp=1, -spring.batch.jobNames=myJobName, run.id=13, -foo=bar}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
`

Comment: What task executor are you using?